# How are you supposed to think of joins in cosmosdb?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am very confused by the cosmosdb documentation on joins. When I think of a join conventionally, I think of 2 tables, with 1 shared id, on which I perform the join. These 2 tables have different schemas, but the result of the join is a combined table with a merge of the columns from both tables. The join for cosmosdb does not seem to me intuitively congruent with that.

I have a collection with heterogenous data. Each document can have a different structure from the next. I want to count the number of documents that have a value that is present in the result set of a subquery. Intuitively, I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) as c
FROM CollectionName as outer
where outer.type = "table"
JOIN ((SELECT c.id from c where c.type = "database") as inner) on outer.databaseId == t.id
// count the number of tables that are in deleted databases
```

It would seem like I would need to do a join on the result of the subquery with the result of the outer query, and then process that resulting table. But I am not understanding right now how to do that:

```
Select COUNT(1)
from Collection outer
where outer.type = 'table'
JOIN (select c.id from c IN outer.databaseId where c.type = "database" and c.state = "deleted")
```

I am constantly getting a 400 with the above query. So how am I supposed to think about joins in cosmosdb?

Answer (score 1):

Cosmos is a document database. It stores and operates on json data which can be in hierarchical format. Joins in Cosmos reference tuples within these hierarchies where they can be projected with other data in the document.

There is a really good article that talks through this at pretty deep level but also have lots of examples too, [Joins in Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-join).

This takes some getting used to writing queries like this but once you get the hang of it you'll be ok. You can easily practice queries using the [Query Playground](https://www.documentdb.com/sql/demo) that has a bunch of sample queries for nutrition dataset with food and ingredients. Or follow along with the families data in the docs. You can create additional items and then write some queries to see how joins work.

Hope that is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already looked at that documentation. I don't believe its clear, and in my opinion the examples do not explain how to think of joins in cosmosdb. In fact, it seems like joins across documents are not possible, only within a document. That was not clear from the documentation above. I only heard about it through a colleague. If there is some other documentation you would recommend, I would greatly appreciate it.